# MDX multiple EXCEPT filter in calculated member

Tags: mdx, member, except

I have following query for calculated member:

```
SUM(
    EXCEPT([Policy].[Policy Status].[Policy Status],[Policy].[Policy Status].&[Void])
    , [Measures].[CountPolicyEndorsesNull]
)
```

What I want is to include another EXCLUDE filter. I have tried following:

```
SUM(
    {EXCEPT([Policy].[Policy Status].[Policy Status],[Policy].[Policy Status].&[Void])}
    *
    {EXCEPT([Invoice].[Invoice Status].[Invoice Status],[Invoice].[Invoice Status].&[Void])}
    , [Measures].[CountPolicyEndorsesNull]
)
```

but it returns more result than the first query. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is correct. The reasons it could be more are the following:

1. You have negative results in ([Invoice].[Invoice Status].&[Void], [Measures].[CountPolicyEndorsesNull])
2. You have a default member set on [Invoice].[Invoice Status].[Invoice Status].

Try returning the following query:

```
select
     [Measures].[CountPolicyEndorsesNull]
on columns,
     {[Invoice].[Invoice Status].DefaultMember,
      [Invoice].[Invoice Status].&[Void]
     }
on rows
from [CubeName]
```

That will get you your culprit.

Comment: I ran it but I don't understand what should I get from it. Here's screenshot: http://img84.imageshack.us/img84/2589/60258089.png ...When I leave only [Measures].[CountPolicyEndorsesNull] on columns I still get the same number.

Comment: Aha! Your `DefaultMember` of `Invoice Status` is `null`, therefore when you do the whole set, you're adding the rest of `Invoice Status` to the result. You can see that by also including, `[Invoice].[Invoice Status].Members` after `&[Void]`. That's why you're getting extra values.

Comment: My educated guess is that the defaultmember is never null. Maybe the dimension, hierarchy or level is wrongly spelled.